# Can't reuse socket in SocketServer.TCPServer

Tags: python, sockets, socketserver

I've got a problem with SocketServer.TCPServer. I'm running a server in a thread. Watching a directory tree with Watchdog. When "on_any_event" runs I need to take down the server and start it again. Unfortunately I can't get SocketServer.TCPServer to reuse the address. I've checked the SocketServer.py file and if `allow_reuse_address` is True it is supposed to set `socket.SO_REUSEADDR` to 1. It still fails with `error: [Errno 98] Address already in use`
though. Sleeping for 10 secs before retrying doesn't help either. Any help?

```
class Server(SocketServer.TCPServer):
    allow_reuse_address = True

class ChangeHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    def __init__(self):
        FileSystemEventHandler.__init__(self)
        self.rebuild()

    def on_any_event(self, event):
        print event
        self.httpd.shutdown()
        self.t.join()
        self.rebuild()

    def rebuild(self):
        self.t, self.httpd = runserver()

def runserver():
    handler = SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
    httpd = Server((HOST, PORT), handler, bind_and_activate=False)
    httpd.server_bind()
    httpd.server_activate()
    t = threading.Thread(target=httpd.serve_forever)
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()
    print "Live at http://{0}:{1}".format(HOST, PORT)
    return t, httpd

if __name__ == "__main__":
    handler = ChangeHandler()
    observer = Observer()
    observer.schedule(handler, path=ROOT, recursive=True)
    observer.start()

    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()
    observer.join()
```

Comment: Which platform are you on: Linux, Windows, OS X? Shouldn't really matter, but...

Comment: Linux. Ubuntu 11.04. Python 2.7.1

Comment: "I need to take down the server and start it again". Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding a `self.httpd.server_close()` after `self.httpd.shutdown()` did the trick.

Answer (score 4):

TCPServer implements the undocumented method server_close(), call this before or after self.t.join() in your event handler, since that is what will actually close the underlying socket. As written it looks like you may be potentially leaking a socket.

```
def on_any_event(self, event):
    print event
    self.httpd.shutdown()
    self.httpd.server_close() # actually close the socket
    self.t.join()
    self.rebuild()
```

Until you close the socket the address actually is in use.

Comment: Undocumented methods are always nice. Thanks for the help :)